# Where is the ojdbc jar file

Tags: java, oracle, classpath

I am using oci driver to connect to oracle 11.2.0 on Linux, I found that under LD_LIBRARY_PATH, there is only libocijdbc11.so but any ojdbc jar files, is that right? For database connection, am I supposed to add this *.so file to java CP?

I can't test it right away because it is on customer production environment, so just want to get what's the gist first, thanks for any guide!

Comment: You should have an OJDBC jar file (like ojdbc14.jar, etc.) somewhere, AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

you can find the ojdbc*.jar files under $ORACLE_HOME/jdbc/lib
and the *.so files must not be included in your CP, but the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH have to be set to the right directory

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse  under project folder->WEB-INF->lib then Right click  lib folder->
Build Path->Configure Build Path->Under Libraries->Click on Add External Jars->Computer->Local Disk (C:)->oraclexe->app->oracle->product->10.2.0->server->jdbc->lib->now select ojdbc14.jar

Directly the path is 
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\jdbc\lib
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\jdbc\lib\ojdbc14.jar

Answer (score 0):

You will get those jars when installing the Oracle Client, the `ojdbcX.jar` files appear in *ORACLE_HOME*/jdbc/lib.

The *.so isn't a java library, and it shouldn't be included in the classpath. It should be available in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Check out the [Verification of a JDBC Client Installation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/getsta.htm#i1007825) section in the Oracle guide.