# how to resolve java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: java.awt.Toolkit.initIDs exception?

Tags: java, eclipse, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have prepared a java stored procedure that captures screenshot. I am calling it using sql developer.

while calling it, I am getting "ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: java.awt.Toolkit.initIDs" error.
How can I resolve this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED demoskr1 AS
package ScreenShot;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;

class demoskr1
{
public static void main(String args[]) 
{     
 System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false");
Robot awt_robot= null;
 try{      
                            Thread.sleep(5000);
                            awt_robot = new Robot();
                            String path = "C:\\Users\\pbafna\\workspace\\shot.jpg"; 
                            BufferedImage Entire_Screen = awt_robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
                            ImageIO.write(Entire_Screen, "jpg", new File(path));
                            System.out.println("Screenshot saved");
     }

  catch (IOException ex) {
      System.out.println("Something went wrong1.");
      }
 catch (InterruptedException ex1) {
  System.out.println("Something went wrong2.");
      }
 catch (AWTException e) {
 System.out.println("Something went wrong.");
      } 
  }
  };
```

Comment: Have You checked your ojdbcXX.jar file? Sometimes UnsatisfiedLinkError is caused by outdated file?
If not, try this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/java-pathfinder/xNG52rzVOQE

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804506/where-is-the-ojdbc-jar-file

Comment: not working still